# Cannot create a simple colored window (OpenGL, GLFW, GLEW)

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, glfw, glew

I have been trying for days to create a simple window with a blue background, but for some unknown reason, I only get a black window. I am compiling a small program using the following 3 files.

- main.cpp

```cpp
#include "wind.hpp"

int main()
{
    wind display;
    display.test();
}
```

- wind.hpp

```cpp
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

class wind
{
public:

    void test();

};
```

- wind.cpp

```cpp
#include "wind.hpp"

void wind::test()
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "LearnOpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewInit();

    std::cout << "Version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;

    static unsigned frameCount = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


        std::cout << ++frameCount << '\r';

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
}
```

I compile a program containing these 3 files and the output is:

[image]

System: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.
Tools used: OpenGL (color), GLFW (for the window), GLEW (for OpenGL calls), CMake (for the building).

Some facts:

- `glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL) != NULL`
- `glewInit() == GLEW_OK`
- In the console, the only output I get is `Version:` . Any subsequent `std::cout` seems to be not executed (no output).
- If I delete the line `std::cout << "Version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;` I get the `frameCount` values in the console (so, main loop is running). But the window is still black.
- If I create a static library with "wind.hpp" and "wind.cpp" (say "libwind.a"), and then I link it to my program ("main.cpp"), and compile... I get the blue window. But I should need to do all this just for creating this simple blue window. I can't understand why it works this way and not the other...

[image]

Comment: your code works on my system... see window and blue background.

Comment: Well, that's weird because, definetly, it doesn't work in my system. What could this mean? Maybe the problem is the building? I am not sure

Comment: @AnselmoGPP What is your OS? Is your graphic driver up to date? Does your system (hardware) provide a OpenGL 3.3 core profile context?

Comment: @Rabbid76 My OS is Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. Yes, my graphic driver is up to date. And my system provides OpenGL 3.3 core profile context. This is not the first time I try to use OpenGL. I have been able to use it via a library that I wrote myself (https://github.com/AnselmoGPP/HansVisual). However, for some reason, I cannot use OpenGL directly in my programs. I am going to add to the post the CMake I used.

Comment: Anything change if you link against Ubuntu's GLFW & GLEW binaries instead of your own?

Comment: @genpfault I couldn't find those precompiled binaries. However, in any case, this should work with my GLFW & GLEW binaries because they already work fine with the library I wrote before (with it, I can draw anything and modify the background). But I cannot write this simple program.